# Find Constraint network - arc-consistency

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, constraint-programming

I have a question about an arc consistency network example. its nothing with code.

i have a network R with Variables X = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8} and Domains D = {1,2,3,4}.
This are my constraints:

[image]

I have the solution fromy my professor. But i dont understand what happend with C24 / why nothing happend with C24.

[image]

I think D2 is 2,3,4 and D4 is default 1,2,3,4. If x2 is not equal x4 (C24), x4 should be 1. I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constraint c(xi,xj) is arc-consistent iff for every value a∈Di there exists a value b∈Dj such that c(a,b) is true (and vice versa with i and j swapped).

If your constraint is *xi < xj*, then the situation *Di={1,2,3}, Dj={1,2,3,4}* is not arc-consistent because there is no xi∈{1,2,3} that makes *xi < 1* true. To get arc-consistency, you must eliminate 1 from Dj.

However, with the constraint *xi ≠ xj* and *Di={1,2,3}, Dj={1,2,3,4}* you already have arc-consistency, because for every *xj∈{1,2,3,4}* there exists an *xi∈{1,2,3}* that makes *xi ≠ xj* true (and for every *xi∈{1,2,3}* there exists an *xj∈{1,2,3,4}* that makes *xi ≠ xj* true).

Comment: first of all thanks for your comment and your help :)
but could you explain it a little bit more because i dont really understand what you mean... sorry

Comment: ah okay. so it is arc-consistency because xi∈ has only 3 values in his domain ( {1,2,3} ) and xj∈ has 4 ( {1,2,3,4} ). So  xi ≠ xj is true because you have 3 values vs 4 values? and not 4 on one side and for on the other side?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the number of elements in the domains.